# Is there any limit to number of records that can be produced to a Kafka topic in single produce command

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have a Databricks Kafka Producer that needs to write 62M records to a Kafka topic. Will there be an issue if I write 62M records at the same time? Or do I need to iterate say 20 times and write 3M records per iteration.

Here is the code.

```
Cmd1 val srcDf = spark.read.format("delta").load("/mnt/data-lake/data/silver/geocodes").filter($"LastUpdateDt"===lastUpdateDt)

Cmd2 val strDf = srcDf
        .withColumn("key",...
        .withColumn("topLevelRecord",...

Cmd3 strDf
 .select(
 to_avro($"key", lit("topic-AVRO-key"), schemaRegistryAddr).as("key"),
 to_avro($"topLevelRecord", lit("topic-AVRO-value"), schemaRegistryAddr, avroSchema).as("value"))
 .write
 .format("kafka")
 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
 .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")
 .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", kafkaKeystoreLocation)
 .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", keystorePassword)
 .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", kafkaTruststoreLocation)
 .option("topic",topic)
 .save()
```

My question is - if strDf.count is 62M, can I directly write it to Kafka or I need to iterate cmd# 3.

Comment: I have added the code above. My question is - if strDf.count is 62M, can I directly write it to Kafka using Cmd3 or I need to iterate Cmd# 3 several times say 20times...and write 3M chunks of data in 1 go.

Comment: Thanks for insight into this Mike. 
The Kafka is installed On-Prem and when I tried writing to Kafka from Databricks Notebook, it timed-out. Out of 62M, 4.9M records were written. I have written a batch Kafka producer; not a spark str. streaming. I used batch because I write to the broker every day only once. Streaming would have taken care as it will send records in microbatch.
In my case, I will try writing in several iterations using a loop. At least I know that using current config. at a time I can write ~4.5M records. Do you think it's the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit for storing data into Kafka using Spark structured streaming for Kafka. You will see below, that your streaming query will create a (pool of) `KafkaProducer` which is used to iterate through the rows in your `Dataframe`. Kafka can handle such amount of messages and there is no limit.

It might be interesting to note that Kafka will buffer some messages into a batch before this batch of messages gets actually written to the brokers. This is steered through the configurations of the [KafkaProducer Configs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html) `linger.ms`, `batch.size` and `max.request.size`, so it might be useful to adjust those settings to your overall set-up.

#### Here is the code of the `spark-kafka-sql` library:

Internally, Spark will create a pool of KafkaProducers in [InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/producer/InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala#L135):

```scala
  private def createKafkaProducer(paramsSeq: Seq[(String, Object)]): Producer = {
    val kafkaProducer: Producer = new Producer(paramsSeq.toMap.asJava)
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      val redactedParamsSeq = KafkaRedactionUtil.redactParams(paramsSeq)
      logDebug(s"Created a new instance of KafkaProducer for $redactedParamsSeq.")
    }
    kafkaProducer
  }
```

Your query is getting then converted into an RDD and for each partition it iterates through the elements in [KafkaWriter.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaWriter.scala#L70):

```scala
  queryExecution.toRdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
      val writeTask = new KafkaWriteTask(kafkaParameters, schema, topic)
      Utils.tryWithSafeFinally(block = writeTask.execute(iter))(
        finallyBlock = writeTask.close())
    }
  }
```

The actual producing of the data will happen in [KafkaWriteTask](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaWriteTask.scala#L48):

```scala
  def execute(iterator: Iterator[InternalRow]): Unit = {
    producer = Some(InternalKafkaProducerPool.acquire(producerConfiguration))
    val internalProducer = producer.get.producer
    while (iterator.hasNext && failedWrite == null) {
      val currentRow = iterator.next()
      sendRow(currentRow, internalProducer)
    }
  }
```